# Detecting opera mini to "hack" position: fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser-detection, opera-mini

I am trying to detect opera mini so that I can put a workaround for my `position:fixed` drawer navigation. I'm using the following bit of code for the browser detection (taken from dev.Opera) :

```
var isOperaMini = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini) === '[object OperaMini]';
    (function() {
        if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini') > -1){
            $('HTML').addClass('opera');
            console.log('opera')
        }else{
            document.getElementsByTagName('body').className+=' no-opera';
            console.log('nuh-uh')
        }
    })();
```

but it is not working. the user agent become true for mozilla also. How can I detect the browser so that I can put in the hack?

** The hack is just to use `position:absolute`, I'll lose the stickiness, but without the hack my site is unusable.

*** I know why `mozilla` is true - according to [this](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) article, user agent is a mess!

Comment: Going by the "Opera Mini" tag - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ this may help you

Comment: says "This property was removed in jQuery 1.9" and I'm using 1.11.1.

Comment: I totally meant the "jQuery tag" - but none the less, my mistake - I should have noted the deprecation tag.

Comment: Do you really need to detect opera? Wouldn't it be better to use [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) to detect if position fixed is supported or not?

Comment: Well, If the project used modernizr, that I could do with it. But it doesn't, and really , most of the code is basic stuff. The only error is this one. adding modernizr for this seems a bit overkill to me, but if I don't find any other way, I might just end up using it.

Comment: Then just use the logic of such a test without including the rest of modernizer: e.g. [modernizr.positionfixed.js](https://gist.github.com/bobslaede/1221602)

Comment: How old is this gist? The current modernizer has only a `position:sticky` detection in the download page. Could it be that they removed the fixed position test?

Comment: @SamiaRuponti I don't know. But you can just use the code in the the `Modernizr.addTest('positionfixed', ` function on its own without modernizer. And use the `ret` value to add the `no-position-fixed` or `position-fixed` class yourself. And if you want to use the current version of modernizer, then it should not a big deal to update the test for the latest version of Modernizer.